# reading input in from a file

Tags: c++, fstream

so I'm a newbie at C++, and I've been poking around on the internet on how to do this, and so far I have this:

```
void includeFile(string name){
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(name);
    string commands;
    while (getline(ifs,commands)){
        commandReader(ifs);
    }
    ifs.close();
}
```

(commandReader is a function that takes an istream)

When I try to compile, I get the error "no matching function for call" and then gives me the line number for the ifs.open(name) line. I've included fstream, so not sure why it's doing this

Comment: In the future, try a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open). Note that there are two overloads of the function and one of them is available in C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, never mind; found the answer right after I posted this.
The solution was to have name.c_string() as the parameter instead, as string support was only added in c++11

Answer (score 0):

As @chris pointed out, pre-C++11, `ifs.open` expects a `char*`, not an `std::string`. Try `ifs.open(name.c_str())`.